# Network is unreachable: connect for repo1.maven.org

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, android-studio

I've gotten Android Studio installed on my work PC, but when I try and build a project I get the error

```
Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':FitnessUnlimited'.
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':FitnessUnlimited:classpath'.
    Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+.
  Required by:
    Siv:FitnessUnlimited:unspecified
      Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build#gradle;0.5.+.
        Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'.
          Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/'.
            Network is unreachable: connect
```

I've put in the Networks proxy details in the settings, and I still get the error. If I put in incorrect details I get an 807 error, which says something to do with authentication, so I think it is correctly reading the proxy settings.

Is there anyway I could maybe download the files it's trying to get here and put them in my project so they don't need download through Android Studio? Speaking to IT they think it's probably a firewalled URL, however, if I load the URL in the browser I can view all the files and download them, so I don't think it is firewalled.

Comment: Nope, our IT department are still looking into the issue. The Android project got put on a back burner until then

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there is a mismatch between how your browser accesses the Internet and how Java does it.

Double check your proxy settings; there must be an error in them somewhere. In a nutshell, Maven uses the standard proxy settings of Java. So you can try to ask your IT how they configure other Java apps.

If you can't get it to work, install a local Maven repository proxy/cache like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi).

See here [how to configure Nexus behind a proxy](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html) and [here for archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/adminguide/network-proxies.html).

Manually downloading usually isn't an option since Maven will probably download thousands of (small) files when you run it the first time.

Comment: We're moving office in a day or two and our phone's aren't working at the moment so I'll call IT when we move and ask them. Speaking to a colleague he's says try getting the IT to use the Proxy login as that worked for him. I'll post my results when I get in touch with IT.

Comment: I have a direct connection but even then I am getting the error. :( please help me...

Comment: @polavishnu: If you want help, ask a question. Don't forget to include every bit of information that is necessary to help you.

Comment: The thing I tried a lot of times and every time I get only error as connection reset. The error is the same as in the question. I have no clue what to ask atleast. People around using the same network are able to use but I am not able to use. I did all kind of stuff that I found regarding such problem .If you can tell me some more means that can solve the problem I can try those and tell you. I uninstalled and reinstalled nearly 10 times. Spent almost a week on that and its of no use. Any help i would feel happy. :)

Comment: The question here is about `Network is unreachable: connect`, not `Connection was reset` - those are two different errors. The first one means there if a firewall between you and the server which swallows your requests. The second error means the server saw you but for some reason, it aborted the connection in the middle. In this case, you need to look into the server logs.